# Populating a database column from a larger one in excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to add data from secondary Excel database to a column in a master database based on the value of another column in the master database.

I have two Excel files, a primary database, and a secondary database. In the primary, I have 3 columns (A,B,C) and the second I have 2 columns (B,D). My request is how to add the values of D column in the primary database knowing that the data in D column must match the associated value in B column?

Note: The secondary database is much larger than the primary

Comment: try use VLOOKUP function or sql query to excel files

Answer (score 0):

Enter the below formula in column D of your primary database sheet and drag it down to fill the complete range,

```
=VLOOKUP(B1,Sheet2!B:D,3,FALSE)
```

Where, `Sheet2` is your secondary database.